# How to prove that $\bigotimes_2 X$ can be normed

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a normed space. Then, $\bigotimes_2X=X\otimes X$ is also a normed space with the  norm
$$\|u\|=\inf\{\sum_{j=1}^n |\lambda_j| \|x_j\| \|y_j\| : u=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jx_j\otimes y_j \},$$
but I haven't gotten to prove that if $\|u\|=0$ implies $u=0$, and I haven't found any proof or hint about that.

Comment: Please see Proposition 2.1 in Ryan's book https://books.google.ca/books?id=MSLUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16

Comment: @OnurOktay: Unfortunately that link doesn't work for me.  But the reference is a good one.  To add some context for the OP: this norm is the "Banach space projective tensor norm" and many introductory texts will explain why it is a norm and not a semi-norm.  If the OP wants a better answer, they might like to explain where they found this.  (It's always a bit odd when a question says "It's well-known that ...  I cannot prove this well-known fact".)

Comment: This question fits better on MSE. But even then, the answer can be found in every book which talks about tensor products of normed vector spaces, so it's easy to google the answer. And of course it is not necessary to take the tensor product of X with itself. This restriction seems odd to me.